# ExtJS 6 gridStore.model.setFields not a function

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I used to work with `ExtJS 4.2` and I used to work using:

```
gridStore.model.setFields(...);
```

Now in `ExtJS 6` I tried to used that and I get:

[image]

> Any clue on what can I use now?

Comment: You could try whether everything works without adding the fields to the model. An up-to-date field definition is not a hard requirement for a model anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `store.setFields(fields)` method intead of `store.model.setFields();`.
Please refer [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-setFields) for more information.